# Observable has no call signature

Tags: typescript, observable

I have the following code snippet which throws the following error: *Observable has no call signature*

```
this.myDict.push(string_key, getObs());
```

where

```
getObs(): Observable<MyType> {
   // make an API call.
   [...]
}
```

myDict is defined as:

```
private myDict: {[key: string]: Observable<MyType>} = {}
```

Comment: You defined myDict as an Object. Where is the push() function defined? Did you mean to use an array?

Comment: So you could use this syntax for a Map: Map<string, Observable<MyType>> = new Map(); Does the error still occur? If so, you will have to share some code of the getObs() function.

Answer (score 0):

I meant to use a map, so what I should've done was `this.myDict[string_key] = getObs()`.